# Restarting (and showing) a stopped activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a background service that can create persistent notifications. When a user clicks on a notification it starts an activity. The user may then press the Home button causing this activity to be stopped.

If the user then clicks on the notification again I want to restart (and show) the same activity (if Android hasn't already destroyed it - which I appreciate it can), so that the GUI state is as the user left it.

How can I achieve this?

Manifest entry for activity

```
<activity android:name=".mrwidget.MrWidget" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">  </action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What I'm after is effectively the same behaviour you get if the activity is selected from the 'recent apps list' you get when you hold down the Home button.

To elaborate - when I click on a notification the first time I successfully create the activity using:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mService.startActivity(i);
```

If I pressed the Home button to switch away from this activity and then held the Home button down to bring up the "recent apps list" and selected the activity from there it works as expected - activity is shown in the state it was left, all good.

I want this same behaviour when I also select the same notification any subsequent time, i.e. it displays the previously created activity. I attempted to do this using:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

where 'activity' is a reference to the activity created the first time the user selected the notification, but doing this doesn't cause the activity to be displayed.

Comment: post the manifest entry for this activity.

Comment: When you say "no joy", can you explain what happens? What are you seeing that is different from what you want to see?

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully address your questions.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, but I still do not understand the problem. What do you think using `REORDER_TO_FRONT` is going to do for you? The activity that you are trying to start is `singleTask`. This means this activity should always be the root activity in the task. Also, when a notification is used, the activity is started by the `NotificationManager`, not by your code, so I don't understand your reference to this code you use to launch the activity: `activity.startActivity(intent);`. Where is that code located? How does it get executed? Please show more of this code

Comment: The app logic is not actually written in java (but lua). So there is a disconnect between the notification and launching the activity. The lua code receives an event generated from clicking on the notification and then decides to launch the activity. What I'm really after is - what does the "recent apps" list that is visible when you hold down the Home button do to bring an activity to the foreground?

Comment: To have the same behaviour as "bringing the app to the foreground", you just need to create an `Intent` that contains the root activity and set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Should work.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "contains the root activity" do you mean create an `Intent` whose context is the root activity?

Comment: No, I mean create an `Intent` where the component is the root activity. This is the activity that has ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in the manifest. The context is irrelevant. Like this: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);`

Comment: Cool. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the same behaviour as "bringing the app to the foreground", you just need to create an Intent that contains the root activity and set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. The root activity is the activity that has ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in the manifest. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you display the notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title", "Text", pendingIntent);
```

Replace `MainActivity` with the class of the Activity you want to launch, and the strings for the notification title and text as you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work for me. I mention the notification really just to give the problem some context, but really I need to launch the stopped activity independent from the notification.